# Proposal for Clinical Informatics Stack

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I have been developing an interest in [clinical informatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_informatics) in recent years, and I was thinking that this subject area would be a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

I am hoping to get feedback on whether Medical Sciences would consider all aspects of clinical informatics on-topic here? My guess is no, because clinical informatics is a diverse field, incorporating clinical aspects, data science, software development, technology and professional skills. For example, this might include coding questions about manipulating data, or interoperability standards.

Medical sciences has [46 questions](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-informatics) under the `health-informatics` tag, though only 13 with accepted answers.

---

### Proposal

I think that clinical informatics is diverse enough to warrant its own stack, and to that end I have submitted a [proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127893/clinical-informatics) on Area51.

I would be grateful for feedback on whether this is a good idea, or if it would have unacceptable overlap with Medical Sciences.

I want to be clear that this is not intended to undermine Medical Sciences in any way. I love it here. I was just thinking that clinical informatics would be a good fit for its own site.

If you think it's helpful and clinical informatics is of interest to you, please consider following it or suggesting questions at [area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127893/clinical-informatics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127893/clinical-informatics), as per the usual Area51 process.

Comment: This is quite a fraught time across the network: https://openletter.mousetail.nl/ - probably not the best environment to try to start a new site.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike Ah, that explains why a flag I raised a for probable AI content over on SO hasn’t been actioned yet.

Comment: Yep, that would be why. It's the same reason there are currently 4 flags on MedSci posts that remain unaddressed after several days and a half-dozen questions still open that should have been closed. I think your idea has merit, and I think you're right that it should be its own site, but now's just not the best time.

Comment: @CareyGregoryisonstrike Thanks. Was just reading up about the strike action - you have my full support.

Comment: Hi Chris, now that the strike has concluded (and I'm now visiting the site--I couldn't stomach looking at all the crap and do nothing), I just want to say that I think clinical / health informatics questions are fully appropriate (disclaimer, I am a board certified clinical informaticist). I'm happy to help set up tags, tag excerpts, and tag wikis and help grow the community as a destination to ask and answer clinical / health informatics questions.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thanks for this. Your support is much appreciated!

Comment: I finally got around to cleaning up the [health-informatics] tag; removing it from questions where it was not relevant. Most of these might have been looking for a generic health tag instead. There are now 38 questions with the [health-informatics] tag.